# Defining a new environment that contains tabularx inside another environment (e.g., center)

Tags: environments, tabularx, center

I'm trying to define a new environment that encloses a `tabularx` environment within some other environment to provide some formatting (such as `center` to centre the whole thing).  The following was my attempt, but it generates the familiar `! File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body` error.  However, I am already using the `\tabularx` command in my definition, which is usually the fix for this error.

The following is my 'MWE' attempt that is broken:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newenvironment{CT}{%
  \begin{center}\tabularx{200pt}{XX}}{%
  \endtabularx\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{CT}
One & Two
\end{CT}
\end{document}
```

If I delete the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` then it runs, while the following is perfectly ok:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{200pt}{XX}
One & Two
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I guess the issue is some subtlety about how `\tabularx` behaves within `\newenvironment` and how it goes looking for the matching `\endtabularx`.

Comment: Use `\center` and `\endcenter`

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  (I'm not used to using those alternatives to the ```center``` environment.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing that `\tabularx` does is

```
\edef\TX@{\@currenvir}%
```

i.e. it saves the current environment name under the name `\TX@`; then the target width is set, and then it goes on grabbing the tokens which make the tabular. I won't post the code here but the crucial issue is that the scanning mechanism  basically keeps collecting tokens until it finds `\end{current_environment}`. With your code

```
\newenvironment{CT}
{%
 \begin{center}%
 \tabularx{200pt}{XX}
}
{%
 \endtabularx
 \end{center}%
}
```

the expansion of `\begin{CT}` results at some point in `\begin{center}`, which sets `\@currenvir` to `center`. Then `\tabularx` starts, sets `\TX@` to `center`, and collects tokens (without expanding them) until it finds `\end{center}`. However, your code does *not* contain `\end{center}` but rather `\end{CT}`. The collecting mechanism has no idea that the `\end{center}` is hidden in `\end{CT}`, so it keeps collecting stuff until it reaches the end of file.

The solution, as egreg already mentioned [in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573100/defining-a-new-environment-that-contains-tabularx-inside-another-environment-e#comment1443810_573100), is to use `\center` and `\endcenter`

```
\newenvironment{CT}
{%
 \center
 \tabularx{200pt}{XX}
}
{%
 \endtabularx
 \endcenter
}
```